# Avoid code duplication with class inheritance python

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, code-duplication

I’m looking for a nice solution to avoid code duplication, my code look like this;

```
class HostEnvironment(AbstractEnvironment):

    def provision(self, wait_for_sshd=True):

        some code

    def __init__(self, layer_info):

        pass

class VCBEnvironment(HostEnvironment):

    def provision(self, wait_for_sshd=True):

        same code

        plus some more code

    def __init__(self, layer_info):
        super(VCBEnvironment, self).__init__(layer_info)
```

Comment: You are *already* using `super()` in the `__init__` method. Why can't you use that instead of `same code` in `VCBEnvironment.provision()` exactly?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: He might not know that `super` can be used for methods besides the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 1):

E.g. like this:

```
class AbstractEnvironment:
    pass

class HostEnvironment (AbstractEnvironment):
    def __init__ (self, layer_info):
        pass

    def provision (self, wait_for_sshd = True):
        print 'some code'

class VCBEnvironment (HostEnvironment):
    def __init__(self, layer_info):
        HostEnvironment.__init__ (self, layer_info)

    def provision (self, wait_for_sshd = True):
        HostEnvironment.provision (self, wait_for_sshd)
        print 'some more code'

print '\ne1'
e1 = HostEnvironment (None)
e1.provision ()

print '\ne2'
e2 = VCBEnvironment (None)
e2.provision ()
```

Output:

```
e1
some code

e2
some code
some more code
```